# OCaml non-blocking client socket

Tags: sockets, ocaml

Is there a way to use a client socket in a non blocking way.

For example, if I create a socket for a client to connect on a server and that I do recursive `recv` on that socket, the last call of `Unix.recv` will block when no data is send and if the connection is not closed by the server.

In C, you can specify flags for both :

- `socket()` and use the `SOCK_NONBLOCK` flag ORed with the socket type
- or `receiv()` with the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flags.

I have looked here :

- http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#TYPEsocket_bool_option
- http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#TYPEsocket_type
- http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#TYPEmsg_flag
- https://ocaml.github.io/ocamlunix/ocamlunix.html#sec119

But I could not find any informations on this.

Comment: 'Recursive `recv()`' doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry, I wanted to say when you call `recv` in a recursive function until all the data are read. Maybe I should have say multiple call to `recv` until all the data are read.

Comment: Have you looked at Lwt (http://ocsigen.org/lwt/2.5.2/manual/)?  It provides lots of tools for non-blocking operations.  For example, `Lwt_unix.recv` (http://ocsigen.org/lwt/2.5.2/api/Lwt_unix#VALrecv) is a non-blocking equivalent to `Unix.recv`.

Comment: @hcarty, no I have not looked at Lwt for this particular matter, but yes I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Unix.set_nonblock`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALset_nonblock) and [`Unix.clear_nonblock`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALclear_nonblock).

Comment: I guess, I will have to deal with the Unix error EINPROGRESS and EAGAIN. Any link to a code example maybe ?